# Why does my simple slopes change after I control for a categorical covariate at the interaction level?

Tags: regression, interaction

I am running an analysis to examine the interaction between var "IESRTotal_C" and "SCSQ_posTotal_C". My simple slope analysis results changed a lot with and without including covariates, so I am hoping someone can help me figure out why that is.

Without including any covariates, my model looks like this:

fit1 = lm(PHQ9Total ~ 1 + IESRTotal_C*SCSQ_posTotal_C, data=Data)

This model yielded a significant interaction effect and further simple slope analyses showed that slopes of IESRTotal_C were significant at all levels of SCSQ_posTotal_C.
[simple slopes without covariates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YshgR.png)

However, after I controlled for covariates at both main effect and interaction levels (and I know controlling at both levels is appropriate to do), my models look like this:

fit2 = lm(PHQ9Total ~ 1 + age_C + highesteducation_R + IESRTotal_C*SCSQ_posTotal_C +
age_C*SCSQ_posTotal_C + IESRTotal_C*age_C + highesteducation_R*SCSQ_posTotal_C +
IESRTotal_C*highesteducation_R, data=Data)

Although the IESRTotal_C*SCSQ_posTotal_C interaction term is still significant, simple slope findings changes a lot:
[simple slopes controlling for covariate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl5XG.png)

Why did the simple slopes change so much? Thank you!!!

I could not figure out at all.

Comment: This kind of purely statistical question belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com (see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Make sure to read through existing threads on the topic of collinearity and its effects on regression coefficients, as you'll find many of them.